# Kubernetes 502 Bad Gateway within the cluster from Python

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I have defined in k8s three deployments and three services.
One service is a PHP-Symfony web app, the two others are Python-Flask services.

The web app calls these services internally (within the Cluster).
The services should also be able to call each other internally.

I can successfully call the services externally via the defined node port and minikube ip from both Python and PHP.

When I try to call the service internally, the web app succeeds but in the Python flask service I receive a 502 Bad Gateway.

**When connecting with sh to the calling service pod, and running same Python commands, it succeeds.**

Python Code

```py
import requests

# success
response=requests.post('http://minikube-ip:30010', json=args)
print(response.text)

# failure
response=requests.post('http://my-service', json=args)
print(response.text)
```

PHP code

```php
// success
$httpClient = HttpClient::create();
$response = $httpClient->request('POST', 'http://my-service', [
                'json' => $args
]);
```

The service that I'm calling is applied by the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-service
          image: my-docker-image

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-service

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30010

  type: NodePort
```

The calling service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serv2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: serv2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: serv2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: serv2
          image: serv2
          imagePullPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serv2
spec:
  selector:
    app: serv2

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30201

  type: NodePort
```

The Web App

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tester-webapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tester-webapp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tester-webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tester-webapp
          image: tester-webapp-image-name

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tester-webapp

spec:
  selector:
    app: tester-webapp

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30299

  type: NodePort
```

The docker container is up and running, and so is the service on minikube.

The service is not meant to run externally, I only used NodePort for testing purposes. I tried to define the service as ClusterIP, but I get the same error.

Net Stat on my-server

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11/nginx: master pr
```

Net Stat on serv2

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13/nginx: master pr
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Can you paste your other service as well?

Comment: I've added the yaml to my question

Comment: Can you share the yaml with ClusterIP, how you have defined. Also can you try doing curl from within your server with pod ip followed by port number.

Comment: Hi, curl works from within the calling server... I've updated the question with some more code example

Comment: exec into the pod, and check if app is listening on the correct ip addresses (please give us `netstat` command output)

Comment: @p10l Added to the question

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Please post netstat output with listening ports (`-l` flag). Preferably `netstat -tulp`.

Comment: Hi @p10l, I updated the question